# What Artificial Neural Network or 'Biological' Neural Network library/software do you use?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, biological-neural-network

What do you use?

Comment: Heh, I have the same answer to this one. Except, writing an ANN was tougher than a GA. Also, my code had to change drastically to change the architecture. I will supply an answer for a package that I have enjoyed though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of different network simulators dependant on how detailed you want to do your sim, and what kind of network you want to simulate.

NEURON and GENESIS are good if you want to simulate full biological networks (Which I'm geussing you probably don't) even down to the behaviour of dendrites etc.

NEST and SPLIT and some others are good for doing population simulations where you create the population on a node-by-node basis and see what the whole population does. This is pretty much the 'industry' standard approach, and is used a lot in research and commercial applications, so there are worth looking into. I know that IBM use SPLIT for some of their research.

MIIND is good if you want to use differential equations to model what a population would do, but this approach is relatively new and computationally expensive (if very cool).

Not sure if that is exactly what you wanted!

(N.B. if you google any of the names in caps along with the word "simulator" you will end up at the relevant web page =)

Comment: I've used Neuron and Genesis etc. but I've never heard of SPLIT nor did google find it for me. Could you give me the link?

Comment: I'm afraid I've never actually used it: my main interest in these simulators is architecture-wise due to my work at Uni, so I'm not sure if it's in the public domain. However I found my information on it in the paper 'Brain-scale simulation of the neocortex on an IBM Blue Gene/L supercomputer' (IBM)

Answer (score 4):

[Fast Artificial Neural Network Library (FANN)](http://leenissen.dk/fann/)  is a free open source neural network library, which implements multilayer artificial neural networks in C with support for both fully connected and sparsely connected networks. Cross-platform execution in both fixed and floating point are supported. It includes a framework for easy handling of training data sets. It is easy to use, versatile, well documented, and fast. PHP, C++, .NET, Ada, Python, Delphi, Octave, Ruby, Prolog Pure Data and Mathematica bindings are available.

[FannTool](http://code.google.com/p/fanntool/) A graphical user interface is also available for the library.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I've wanted to play around with any data mining algorithm quickly, I just load up [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/).  It's pretty complex but it implements a lot of algorithms (including neural networks) with a lot of customizability.  Plus, it has some visualizations for NNs.

Answer (score 3):

It is old, but I have always used [NeuroShell 2](http://www.wardsystems.com/neuroshell2.asp) when not using my own code. Unfortunately, it is not free. I think The newer NeuroShells are designed only for predicting stocks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to experiment with deep learning, you should look into
Theano
Pylearn2 (which is based on Theano)